# In .Net many classes are thread-safe if they are static, how is that implemented?

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety, clr, clr4.0

For many classes in the .NET frameworks, MSDN describes thead safety as:

> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are
>   thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread
>   safe.

How is that implemented? is there a syntactic sugar that happens there? or is it implemented inside the class in some way?

Thanks.

Comment: I always tend to crack open an assembly with [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) to see if miracles happen...

Comment: If it just boilerplate verbiage that gets copy/pasted into every MSDN article.  It is often inaccurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is just an implementation detail of those classes. It just means that the developers for those static methods took care of any thread-safety issues.

It is not a language or framework feature that static methods are thread-safe.

Comment: It is a library guideline that static members should be made thread-safe. It is indeed not something that happens automatically.

Comment: @Knagis - these are not static method, it's instance methods of instances stored in static members, or did I misunderstand?

Comment: You did misunderstand the MSDN doc. It says exactly the opposite - that those instance methods will not be thread-safe.